# Proper way to print different debug messages in C?

Tags: c, debugging, stderr

I need to print msg1 and msg2 for the same error when compiled with and without DEBUG flag. E.g.

```
      fprintf( stderr,
#ifdef DEBUG
                      "error msg1 %s",__FILE__
#else
                      "error msg2"
#endif
              );
```

or other way might be to pass these `msg1` and `msg2` to a function and print it using `vfprintf()`.
Probably, The second method would have run time overhead. So, I am just wondering what could be better way of doing this?

E.g. A use case might be that the code need to be compiled with `info` and `debug` flags. `info` might be user related messages and `debug` for debugging purpose.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Just asking: are you sure you want to filer an _error_ message?

Comment: Yes, I want to have different error messages. Things like info, verbose etc.

Comment: Please give some more details on your use-case and its background.

Comment: You might be better off with a logger that has various levels, debug, info, error, and allows you to turn them on and off.

Comment: @alk I see. It was a typo.

Comment: @alk: not really, IIRC you are allowed to pass extra stuff to printf and it will just be ignored.

Comment: You could use a [library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27552064/7076153) that do the job.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Correct, for a variadic function behaviour is well defined. My bad, sry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usualy the traces are used in the code to help debug it, so for example in your NULL pointer tests you can add smth like `if (ptr==NULL) DEBUG("Entering Null pointer");`. I'am just telling you that because i don't udrestand why you want use both `msg1` and `msg2`.

For me i usually use a macro `DEBUG` and a global variable `verbose` :

```
#define DEBUG(...)\
if(verbose && SHOW_ERROR) {\
printf("Error : %s, %d",__FUNCTION__, __LINE__);\
printf(__VA_ARGS__);\
}\
else if (verbose && SHOW_WARNING) {\
printf("Warning : %s, %d",__FUNCTION__, __LINE__);\
printf(__VA_ARGS__);\
}
```

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SHOW_ERROR 1
#define SHOW_WARNING 2

int verbose = 1; 
int main()
{
  DEBUG("THIS WILL SHOW ERROR MSG");
  verbose = 2;
  DEBUG("THIS WILL SHOW WARNING MSG");
}
```

Hope i help.

Comment: Wouldn't this create readability issue.? As I read somewhere, macros are meant for one liner code.

Comment: @ShivendraMishra, I don't think so, a macro by definition is a code chunck that has a name. so in case we have a code on multiple line and we want replace it with a Macro why not

Comment: I believe __VA_ARGS__ is different for different compilers e.g. with  gnu99 and on windows.

Comment: "VA_ARGS is different for different compilers " Could you please explain more, what kind of problem you are facing ?

Comment: some compilers shows warning "VA_ARGS can only appear in the expansion of a C99 variadic macro". Even if I add c99 flag. I followed https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html . But it seems gcc is messing up with the parameters.

Comment: You mean you are using a C99 compiler and get this error, strange. Note \__VA_ARGS__ and not VA_ARGS if you are sure u can post a new question

Answer (score 1):

An unconditional call to `vfprintf` does carry some additional overhead for packaging the extra parameter, `a`, for use with the variable-argument list function. Moreover, conditional compilation allows the compiler to notice that the call to `fprintf` in `DEBUG` mode does not pass parameters other than the format string, and replace it with `fputs("error msg1", stderr)`<sup>*</sup>

However, this overhead is tiny, and you are unlikely to notice any of it, because the writing happens unconditionally, and it is going to dominate the timing of the call.

<sup>*</sup> It is uncommon for `DEBUG` output to provide *less* details than the non-debug one; usually, it is the other way around.

Comment: I am worried about this function is being called very frequently and this tiny overhead will create impact in long run.

Comment: @ShivendraMishra The observation of the long run is simply not true: an overhead of 0.01% will not be noticeable, no matter how long is your run. Given that the function does I/O, on `stderr`, the impact of parameter passing will be on that order of magnitude, because I/O on `stderr` is thousands of times more expensive than packaging an extra parameter into VA list.

Comment: Agreed, Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Your debug flag is a preprocessor macro, so the error message will be chosen at compile time, is this the behavior that you want?

I would suggest a slightly different approach:

```
#define PRINT_INFO(msg1,msg2) if(dbg){fprintf(stderr,msg1);}\
                              else{fprintf(stderr,msg2);}
```

where the `dbg` flag can be turned on and off at run time

You can play around even more using [variadic macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html):

```
#define PRINT_INFO_VAR(msg1,msg2...) if(dbg){fprintf(stderr,msg1);}\
                                     else{fprintf(stderr,msg2);}
```

And for the example you gave it would look like this:

```
PRINT_INFO_VAR(msg1,msg2,a)
```

Comment: @ShivendraMishra added variadic argument support
if you can give more background, I can probably fine tune the answer.

Comment: Explained use case in questions.

Comment: @ShivendraMishra: "*notice that msg2 has a.*" which `a`?